# Auth0 omitting scopes when refreshing access token

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm using `auth0-react` to manage authentication in my SPA, and it's been working fine for many months. However, recently it stopped supporting the use of refresh tokens.

I believe my app is using a fairly standard structure, as defined in the documentation for [v1.12.1](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/tree/v1.12.1#configure-the-sdk). All is fine when I originally log in: the `/authorize` endpoint returns what's expected and triggers an immediate call to `/token` with `grant_type=authorization_code` in the payload. This succeeds: HTTP 200 and a response that includes `refresh_token` and `scope`, among other fields.

However, when I make an API call after the access token has expired, a call to `/token` is triggered which receives an HTTP 400 with body: `{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"User is not authorized to the audience for those scopes"}`. A bit of experimentation shows that the `/token` request has only the following four fields in its payload: `client_id`, `redirect_uri`, `refresh_token` and `grant_type=refresh_token`. When I make a manual call with the same details but I add `scope`, the request succeeds.

As such, I *believe* my question is: is there a way to enforce the `getAccessTokenSilently` function to include the `scope` parameter in a `/token` request with `grant_type=refresh_token`? Alternatively, can anyone guess what may have changed for this issue to appear unexpectedly a couple of weeks ago? (I believe I made no code changes that could be relevant: in fact, I made almost no changes to my Javascript in this time, and the problem persists on reverting to old code.)

I'm not an expert on authentication flows, so if my question is unclear or you can think of any further things to check, please let me know.